# Optimizing performance Hearthstone Linux

Tags: hearthstone, linux, performance

I have to use a weak machine right now, so I have a huge lag while playing Hearthstone. So I was wondering if there a way to optimize its performance ;?
Currently I have turned graphics to "Low" for the purpose, but I do not know, what more can I do? And I am running it on Linux if this is of some importance for the subject.

Thanks! {:

Comment: The emulation probably costs you a lot of computation resources, so running it on Windows on the same machine would certainly improve performance. You might want to consider a parallel Windows install. Other than that, there's not much you can do. I have had the same problem and just acceptet that I'll have to play on another machine if I want to play lag-free.

Comment: Lag as in buttons still clickable or lag as in hearthstone doesn't react at all? The first one is network lag and the second one is the application itself. Anyhow if you really enjoy hearthstone install windows. I wasted so much time figuring out how to make game x or y work in Linux...

Comment: how do you run it? in a VM oder with wine?

Comment: Wine, but I already gave up on the idea of playing hearthstone on Linux. (:

Answer (score 1):

Try closing the battle net launcher rather than having it go to the tray. This fixed the lag issue for me you can do that from the battle net launcher settings